# Why doesn't my Selection List filter my Category Comparison Chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using the new SQL Server Reporting Services Mobile Reports in 2016.

I have added a Selection List to a report that's based on a dataset. I have checked the option to filter my dataset when a selection is made, but when I save the report and view it, nothing changes when I make a selection.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to RTM :)

Turns out that even after I filter a dataset with a navigator, I need to go to each visualization and specify which filters affect that visualization by using the "Options..." menu of the fields in the Data tab